# Rename and add a number to all folders in a directory

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, rename, batch-rename

I have a simulation folder on hpc which contains time directories from 0 to 50 with a step of 0.1 (so 501 folders in total with their names as 0, 0.1, 0.2.. and so forth).

Example output of `ls`:

```
0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 ..... 49.5 49.6 49.7 49.8 49.9 50
```

I want to add a specific number, lets say 60 to all the folder names such that the new folder names will be from 60 to 110.
Required output of `ls`:

```
60 60.1 60.2 60.3 60.4 60.5 ..... 109.5 109.6 109.7 109.8 109.9 110
```

There are several similar questions I found on the site but none that point to a solution to this.

Can anyone please help me out with this problem?!

Thanks!

Edit: The directories are in Ubuntu 22.04.3

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example with input and expected output?

Comment: Please add the OS and version number to your question.

Comment: [Do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Use plain text instead.

Comment: In your example is not +60, but **100** !

Comment: Thanks for the answer..! It works. Also, apologies for uploading the example as image.. It was not clear when it was mentioned in the text earlier. But the example is +60 (also in the image).. It's just that when you do 'ls' it displays folder names starting from 100 and not 60.. In any case, it was my bad for not making it clearer. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Please change the screenshots of text into the actual text if you can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename files with count?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187477/how-to-rename-files-with-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
$ ls
0.1  0.2  0.3
$ rename -n 's|\./(.*)|$1 + 100|e' ./*
rename(0.1, 100.1)
rename(0.2, 100.2)
rename(0.3, 100.3)
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

Comment: While `./*` will work as a safety measure for possible command injection (*especially with `e`*) ... You might want to exclude it from the match with e.g. a look-behind pattern so that the calculation will work without errors on e.g. `./0.2 + + 100` where `./` will error out and you might also want to limit matching numeric filenames as well for the same reason like `rename -n 's/(?<=\.\/)[0-9.]+$/$& + 100/e' ./*`

Comment: Well spotted, tried without `./`. Post edited accordingly.